# How AppleScript can get STDIN inside the code?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

Google suggests

```
echo "input" | osascript filename.scpt
```

with `filename.scpt`

```
set stdin to do shell script "cat"
display dialog stdin
```

However, I could get only blank dialog: it has no text. How can I get stdin from AppleScript at the version?

My OS version is OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that "set stdin to do shell script "cat"" used to work. I can't get it to work in 10.8 though and I'm not sure when it stopped working. Anyway, you basically need to get the echo command output into a variable which can then be used as an argument in the osascript command. Your applescript needs to handle arguments too (on run argv). And finally, when you use osascript you must tell an application to "display dialog" otherwise it will error.

So with all that said here's a simple applescript which handles arguments. Make this the code of filename.scpt.

```
on run argv
    repeat with i from 1 to count of argv
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            display dialog (item i of argv)
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

Here's the shell command to run...

```
var=$(echo "sending some text to an applescript"); osascript ~/Desktop/filename.scpt "$var"
```

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was very helped your detailed answer! I could get stdin now ;)

Answer (score 8):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.comp.lang.applescript/1v0s0Tkn1bM/UBdqNBNoulwJ), as of 10.8 AppleScript now aggressively closes standard in.  By sliding it out of the way to an unused file descriptor, it can be saved.  Here's an example of doing that in bash.

Here we get at it again with a `cat` subprocess reading from the magic `fd`.

```
echo world | osascript 3<&0 <<'APPLESCRIPT'
  on run argv
    set stdin to do shell script "cat 0<&3"
    return "hello, " & stdin
  end run
APPLESCRIPT
```

Will give you:

```
hello, world
```

Comment: Thanks for your information! The latest way is very helpful and I could work your sample code at my PC.

Comment: It should, but I can't verify.  The FD redirection trick is older than the hills, so if the rest works on prior versions then I would expect this to as well.

Comment: I'd love to have an explanation of what `3<&0` means. I consider myself an intermediate shell scripter and have never seen this before.

Comment: Copy and pasted this gives the error syntax error: The run handler is specified more than once, or there were top-level commands in addition to the run handler. (-2752

Comment: @SridharSarnobat `3<&0` assigns the standard file descriptor 0 to another number 3 (higher than 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr). When AppleScript runs, it reads the script from stdin, then shuts the file descriptor 0 close, so the script can't read from it anymore. However, 3 stays open and also points to stdin. `cat 0<&3` again swaps the descriptors back, sliding in 3 as cat's stdin. More generally: open files are passed to programs under numbers, where 0 to 2 are standard input, output and error output; however a parent process can also pass arbitrary more file descriptors.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment on answers, but I think there's something important worth pointing out here...

The solution in [@regulus6633's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975766/365498) is ***not*** the same as piping data into `osascript`. It's simply stuffing the entire pipe contents (in this case, `echo` output) into a variable and passing that to osascript as a commandline argument.

This solution may not work as expected depending on what's in your pipe (maybe your shell also plays a part?)... for example, if there are null (`\0`) characters in there:

```
$ var=$(echo -en 'ABC\0DEF')
```

Now you might think `var` contains the strings "ABC" and "DEF" delimited by a `null` character, but it doesn't. The null character is gone:

```
$ echo -n "$var" | wc -c
    6
```

However, using [@phs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18732806/365498) (a true pipe), you get your zero:

```
$ echo -en 'ABC\0DEF' | osascript 3<&0 <<EOF
>   on run argv
>     return length of (do shell script "cat 0<&3")
>   end run
>EOF
7
```

But that's just using zeros. Try passing some random binary data into `osascript` as a commandline argument:

```
$ var=$(head -c8 /dev/random)
$ osascript - "$var" <<EOF
>   on run argv
>     return length of (item 1 of argv)
>   end run
>EOF
execution error: Can’t make some data into the expected type. (-1700)
```

Once again, @phs's answer will handle this fine:

```
$ head -c8 /dev/random | osascript 3<&0 <<EOF
>  on run argv
>    return length of (do shell script "cat 0<&3")
>  end run
>EOF
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but the original AppleScript seems to try to do something not allowed with osascript.

If in the original filename.scpt this line:

```
display dialog stdin
```

Is changed to:

```
tell application "System Events" to display dialog stdin
```

Then passing a value via stdin (as opposed to command line arguments) definitely still works in 10.7.5 Lion, maybe 10.8 Mountain Lion too.

Comment: `stdin` appears to be closed on 10.8